# consteval declaration mismatch works in MSVC but not in GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I've written the following program that compiles with msvc but not with gcc and clang. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgDMpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHObxocjeWADUJvFuTgoExJisB9gmGgCCBJgsSQb3B0eCu6qX1zcnxF4OuwAGvsAOxWW5oBgnTAANzEuxOTEcyF2oQIu2AmAIEDmB3BNzRuyoON2kJOeO%2BJhBABEKbcAPT0tCPOiYBS7ADuhAQuxYChhKKiXnRDFQ6K5BB5wGQKMM6FJBiM%2B1u90ez0wr0Jn3i2FR70Br212BAIEx2NxYN2ZwIywYHzxoOpu2VN0pt0JLCYoRJVPxzrJ91USWIevReH28SdBsOkkuJrNOIdlJpHAWtE4AFZeH4OFpSKhOG5rNYEUsVph9mZ4jxSARNKmFgBrfwZ/ScSTZ%2Bv5zi8BQgDS1%2BsLOCwJCYVTVYUkciUBrABTKQyYWhCBCoDk5mvMpJ0JEZRdhFdrjdd7esuICpJJAD6MK4AE5r%2BqTtfVAA2aRn%2BjEADywtX645nm47VDcxDzj2gQTsgdT4DmvD8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOouY6HoirGMWlj6HgUR9pACyoEkjgCH2HD0ic6AoIRFhmHmChlqsegMaEB7LgBJ7cLwpyYGsNYcsQTBJJwPBppmnY4d2HDYNBU4hu%2Bki8vyKJ3veAB0z7ohARaWNYpC7LghAkJW1ZzEJQ4LAg5xYHEOKkM2ZitumHAdqQQG8AWHC9v2g44cOMCICAIHIKpM4QHOC5LkegHSbwX57gIvFJQJeZfgM87MEkChrgQpC5b%2B/7Hn5UGgeBtG8FFsGhJBiHCKI4hoS1mFqF2ugBPhTEmURtAkWRrmUdRUKcAAtAxBzUqYg0sWxHGoUMcGZfxm5CWcom8OJkkpbJHBZr5XYBcpk5EGpAAcb5TR%2BGIyrsECnF4DCNnMz3GVYRHmfgV3WVwtkhVocxNv4ki6fe0Mw7DsNvm23nyXmAVBQOdahaQI4RVFMUUHFtUbZVKWlagLLPPuiWbaeZM7t%2BKD4VwGYaAOZV/sIxMKVFYEQYF1UwQQcHNbIyHtdInVKN1Cm6Ik/ULT9NjDaR8AUVRGS0TNgtzfL1isb2K1cYLPFU5zNbCbtpD7VJglHSdVXnSpAOqLd90adshjALsTO6RoPtfcxZkWQDGxA3ZoXgx5iM%2BfbkF9uj9mI2YyP%2BZBGOgwsMKxGkziSEAA%3D)

```
template<int x>
struct X {
consteval static int get();
int f() const;
};
//compiles with msvc but not with gcc and clang 
template<int x> int X<x>::get(){ return x; }  


int main() {
  constexpr int i = X<4>::get(); 
}
```

As we can see MSVC compiles the above demo while GCC and Clang reject it. GCC says:

```
error: redeclaration 'static int X<x>::get()' differs in 'consteval' from previous declaration
    8 | template<int x> int X<x>::get(){ return x; }
      |                     ^~~~
<source>:4:22: note: previous declaration 'static consteval int X<x>::get()'
    4 | consteval static int get();
      |                      ^~~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:12:30: error: 'static consteval int X<x>::get() [with int x = 4]' used before its definition
   12 |   constexpr int i = X<4>::get();
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>: At global scope:
<source>:4:22: warning: inline function 'static consteval int X<x>::get() [with int x = 4]' used but never defined
    4 | consteval static int get();
      |                      ^~~
```

I want to know which compiler is correct here according to the C++20 standard.

Comment: What are the compiler flags and which versions are you using?

Comment: Not sure if it is correct or not but `template<int x> consteval int X<x>::get(){ return x; }` works with all three compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSVC is wrong to accept this code silently. This is non-conforming, so it should at least print a diagnostic if it offers an extension (but I suspect it's accepted at all due to a bug).

> **[dcl.constexpr]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-4)  If any declaration of a function or function template has a constexpr or consteval specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the same specifier.

IIUC this rule exists due to some ODR-related implications. So GCC/Clang rejecting it outright is more sound.